# Mutual dependence/associations

Tags: correlation, pca

I have three related questions about measuring the association within sets of data:

A. Imagine I were to try and test the hypothesis that the IQ of individuals in same sex couples are correlated (e.g., that if one person is higher than a average so will their partner; and vice versa). Despite intuitively considering linear correlations for this task, there seems to be an issue with this. Consider this dataset:
115 125;
75 100;
50 65

Because there is no significance to who the "first" and who the "second" person is, the same data set could have just as easily been displayed this way:
125 115;
75 100;
65 50

The Correlation analysis, in this case, will produce a different number. The question is, therefore, whether there is some alternative to correlations that does not assume that X and Y are meaningfully different.

B. And what about bigger sets? Say oranges come in bags of six and I want to see if oranges with similar size tend to be bagged together.
For example, the metric for the set including {[100 95 90 85 80 75],[70 65 60 55 50 45]} would be higher than the one for the set including {[100 95 90 70 65 60],[85 80 75 55 50 45]} because in the first set, the higher-than-average values tend group together (and so do the lower-than-average ones). If the answer to A would have been correlation, the answer here seems to be to use PCA, but the same issues arise.

C. Finally, an extension to B: what if some of the bags would have 6 oranges, but some would have 5, 4, 3 or even 2 oranges. Is there a metric that would measure their mutual tendency despite the data having sets of difference sizes?

Thank you!

Comment: The first question might be answerable, but (B) and (C) are strange insofar as they don't permit any kind of "correlation" to be computed in the first place, thereby casting doubt even on what (A) is trying to get at.  You might consider limiting your question to (A) or offering examples of what (B) and (C) are trying to refer to.

Comment: I would look into programs for dyadic data analysis. David Kenny has written a lot about this.

Comment: Your question (A point at least, and maybe other two as well ) is right the question of _intraclass correlation coefficient_. Read about it (start with Wiki). There are several versions of that correlation, the most straighforward to solve your problem (A) is the Fisherian "unbiased" version also called pair-combinatorial one.